# Scraping non formatted json

Tags: python, json, scrapy

My online json file is like

```
data(
      [
        {
           "CCODE": "15ET",
            "CNAME": "JOE",
            "CAGE": 32
        },{
           "CCODE": "15ET",
            "CNAME": "JOE",
            "CAGE": 32
        },{
           "CCODE": "15ET",
            "CNAME": "JOE",
            "CAGE": 32
        }
      ]
    )
```

I am trying to scrap it using scrapy , but the code `json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())` is giving `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value` as the json format is incorrect . Is there any workarounds for this problem .

Comment: what type does body_as_unicode() return? if it is a string then print it out and see if it some how affected the some of the characters which would affect how json.loads operates.

Comment: if the text you posted is in a `str` obj, you can try `json.loads(d.replace("data","").strip('()'))`

Comment: `json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())` is in scrapy or your code? The `data(...)` wrapping this sample isn't json making me wonder what this page really is? Is it some javascript fragment?

Comment: @tdelaney  `json.loads` code is my code . The data is taken using jquery ajax method from the json file  with `dataType :  'jsonp' ` and `jsonpCallback : 'data'` .

Comment: Please do a print response.body_as_unicode() and paste the response. Will know what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expression to clear it from some JS stuff first and next you can use `json.loads()`:

```
json_str = re.search( r'data\((.+)\)$', response.body, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
data = json.loads(json_str)
```

**UPDATE**
For Python 3 you need something like this:

```
json_str = re.search( r'data\((.+)\)$', response.text, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: @anoop-d can you show your FULL code? Because I have tested my snipped on your string and it's works

Comment: the code is simple scrapy code `    def parse(self, response):
        json_str = re.search( r'data\((.+)\)$', response.body, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Your `response.text` doesn't look EXACTLY like you posted

Comment: May be you have some other information in it... My regex works with EXACTLY same response text